# How to fix Broken PIPE ERROR occuring while using TQDM python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

While using tqdm for using large number of grequests I got below error.

The code I am using is

```
(
            grequests.get(u, proxies=proxy, session=session, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
            for u in tqdm(urls, desc="Current check_in progress", miniters=1, mininterval=1)
        )
```

and the error is

```
File /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py line 943 in __init__ args locals
self.display()
File /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py line 1323 in display args locals
self.sp(self.__repr__() if msg is None else msg)
File /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py line 250 in print_status args locals
fp_write('\r' + s + (' ' * max(last_len[0] - len_s, 0)))
File /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py line 244 in fp_write args locals
fp_flush()
```